# How can I convert timestamps toUTCString and prevent browser changing the date to local timezone?

Tags: javascript, arrays, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm having an array full of timestamps like:

```
let tAxe = [1548546272000, 1548546287000, 1548546303000, 1548546318000, 1548546333000];
```

I'm trying to convert each timestamp to a human readable date. Can I prevent this date to be converted by the browser to current timezone? This tAxe variable is used in an amChart4 library to generate the graph.

I'm thinking of a loop but I'm not sure how to write exactly the code

```
for (i = 0; i < tAxe.length; i++) { 
  // I don't know how to write exactly the conversion

}
```

Comment: `but also prevent this new string to be converted by the browser to current timezone` toUTCstring won't do that

Comment: `whatYouNeed = tAxe.map(d=>new Date(d).toUTCstring())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set `dateFormatter.utc` to true and amCharts will do the rest for you:

```
chart.dateFormatter.utc = true;
```

Here is an example using the timestamps you shared:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.dateFormatter.utc = true;

chart.data = [
  {date:1548546272000, value: 12},
  {date:1548546287000, value: 15},
  {date:1548546303000, value: 13},
  {date:1548546318000, value: 17},
  {date:1548546333000, value: 14},
];

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/samuel-p/pen/GRKWoZN) is a code pen which also shows the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js). 
A Windows file time uses an epoch of Jan 1, 1601. A JavaScript Date uses Jan 1, 1970. You will need to adjust the value accordingly.

Since all JavaScript numbers are IEEE floating point numbers, when you start working with values that large, you can get rounding errors. This can be avoided by truncating the string instead of dividing.

```
var s = "130459385299470000";
var t = +s.substring(0, s.length-4);
var e = Date.UTC(1601,0,1);
var dt = new Date(e + t);
```